# JDA Event getters returning null & getting all members in a role returning only the bot itself

Tags: java, discord-jda

I am trying to create a discord bot that adds/removes roles from a guild member when they add/remove a reaction from a message, and remove all members from a specific role when a trigger happens.

Every time I do `event.getmember` for the `onMessageReactionRemove` event, I always get null for some reason. When I also try to get all the members that have a specific role and put it in a list, I only get the bot itself in the list. I also don't get any errors for when the bot tries to remove all members from a specific role. I got this bot to work a day ago, but I don't know why it doesn't work now.

On the documentation, it says that it will return null if the user isn't in the guild anymore, but when I removed a reaction, I was still in the guild.

Here is the error message when the bot tries to get the member who removed a reaction, this error is fired when the bot tries to remove a role from a member:

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Member may not be null
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.utils.Checks.notNull(Checks.java:64)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.entities.GuildImpl.removeRoleFromMember(GuildImpl.java:1209)
    at me.david.tskmanager.eventlisteners.EventChannelsEventListener.onMessageReactionRemove(EventChannelsEventListener.java:47)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:440)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:82)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:69)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:150)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageReactionHandler.onRemove(MessageReactionHandler.java:200)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.MessageReactionHandler.handleInternally(MessageReactionHandler.java:146)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:36)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:947)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:834)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:812)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:985)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    public void onMessageReactionRemove(@Nonnull MessageReactionRemoveEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event.getMember());
        if (trackedMessages.contains(event.getMessageId()) && event.getReactionEmote().getEmote().equals(event.getGuild().getEmoteById(emoteID))) {
            GuildCache cache = GuildCache.getCache(event.getGuild().getId());
            System.out.println(cache.getAttendingEventRole());
            event.getGuild().removeRoleFromMember(event.getMember(), cache.getAttendingEventRole()).queue();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageUpdate(@Nonnull MessageUpdateEvent event) {
        if (trackedMessages.contains(event.getMessageId()) && event.getMessage().getContentRaw().startsWith("[FINISHED]")) {
            GuildCache cache = GuildCache.getCache(event.getGuild().getId());
            List<Member> members = new ArrayList<>();
            members.addAll(event.getGuild().getMembersWithRoles(cache.getAttendingEventRole()));
            for (Member member : members) {
                event.getGuild().removeRoleFromMember(member, cache.getAttendingEventRole()).queue();
                System.out.println("removed role");
            }
            trackedMessages.remove(event.getMessageId());
        }
    }
```

If you need more code snippets just comment what you need.

**EDIT**: The problem where the `event.getMember` only returning null is solved.

**EDIT 2**: So what Moorhuhn said in the comments helped me to solve the other problem. The problem what that the bot only cached the members in a voice chat so it couldn't get the members with a specific role.

Comment: You may look into gateway intents. https://github.com/DV8FromTheWorld/JDA/wiki/Gateway-Intents-and-Member-Cache-Policy

Comment: I don't know how exactly this is going to help me fix my problem. @Moorhuhn

Comment: You can just use `event.getUserId()` instead of the member which is nullable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `event.getUserId()` instead. Discord doesn't provide member information for reaction remove. The `removeRoleFromMember` method also accepts user ids: [removeRoleFromMember(String, Role)](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/Guild.html#removeRoleFromMember(java.lang.String,net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Role))

Comment: Alright now that problem is solved, I just need to solve the problem of the method `getMembersWithRoles` only getting the bot itself.